# Dynamic filter: change value1 based on input

Tags: sapui5

Im quite new to UI5, did some courses on OpenSAP and now tried to apply it in my own environment.

I have a long list of customers (>4000) and I want to implement a searchfield to search for customer names. For performance reasons I don't want to load all customer entries at once but still apply the search on all users (Using the growth functunality only the first entries to the growthThreshold were found via searchfield.
While searching for a solution I noticed that server sided filtering was an option. I now set up a filter but can't figure out how to change the value1 parameter based on the input of my searchfield (If I hardcode different values for the value1 parameter the filtering works just fine.)

I already searched for solutions and some issues with databinding and dynamic filters came up but I don't know if this is the issue for me.

Table:

```
<Table id="table" width="auto" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" mode="MultiSelect"
    items="{ path: '/CustomerSet', parameters: {$$operationMode: 'Server'},filters : {path : 'Name', operator: 'Contains', value1 : ''}}" 
    growing="true" growingThreshold="20" growingScrollToLoad="false">
<!-- Table content -->
</Table>
```

Searchfield:

```
<SearchField id="searchField" search="onSearch" width="auto"/>
```

Controller:

```
onSearch : function (oEvent) {
    var aFilter = [], sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query"),
    oList = this.getView().byId("table"),
    oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
    if (sQuery) {
        aFilter.push(new Filter('Name', 'Contains', sQuery));
    }
    oBinding.filter(aFilter);
}
```

The search function is copied and slightly adjusted from a tutorial and works great with the not server sided filtering.

With server sided filtering however, if I now type in some customer name and hit the search button, nothing happens at all.
As I said Im new to UI5 and might do some obvious mistake.
Also if there is a different solution besides using server sided filtering I would also be interested to know.

Thank you for your help!

Ascanio

Comment: presume your apis are using oData -  pushing filtering server assumes you are engaing an oData endpoint that has filtering implemented. How have you implemented your APIs?

Comment: Hello Bernard, sorry for the late response. I haven't implemented the oData Service myself. That's why Im no sure what to answer you. I just checked the services metadata and I can't find anything about filtering beeing implemented. However, as I wrote above, if I hardcode the filtering criteria the entries are being filtered, isn't that a sign that filtering is implemented?

Comment: @Ascani0 As mentioned above, `$filter` needs to be implemented by the OData service provider. Try filtering without UI5 just by entering the URL accordingly in the browser. For example: https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$format=json&$filter=substringof('Alfreds',CompanyName) (== `new Filter("CompanyName", "Contains", "Alfreds"`). See OData's [URI-conventions](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)